# cronjob to go to database node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I have this:

```
cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var getTexts = new cronJob( '13 12 * * *', function(){
    var viewConformationEmails = "select * from clients";
    ibmdb.open(ibmdbconn, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(viewConformationEmails, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else if (!err) {
                console.log("Success")
            }
    
            var arrayOfNumbers = []
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                arrayOfNumbers.push(rows[i].PHONE_NUMBER)
            }
            console.log("arrayOfNumbers: ", arrayOfNumbers)
    
            conn.close(function() {
            });
        });
    });
})
```

What I am doing here is setting a `cronjob` for **12:13 pm** today, which already passed. And within that cronjob function, I go to my database and get the phone numbers, put them in an array, and then try to log the array.

However, at **12:13 pm** it didn't go through. I tried this with `twillo` as well, and it went through. but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, or if I can even do what I am looking for. Is this possible

Comment: thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `cron` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#cron-ranges), the range parameters are:

> Seconds: 0-59 
> Minutes: 0-59 
> Hours: 0-23 
> Day of Month: 1-31 
> Months: 0-11 (Jan-Dec) 
> Day of Week: 0-6 (Sun-Sat)

So, if you want to run schedule your task on 12:13pm, you need to set your parameters in this way:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

console.log('Before job instantiation');
const job = new CronJob('* 13 12 * * *', function() {
    const now = new Date();
    console.log('Task runs at', now);
});
console.log('After job instantiation');
job.start();
```

**Note:** setting this time without specifying the `Seconds` parameter, will run the task at every second between 12:13pm ~ 12:14pm internally. So, if you want to run your task once at a specific time, define the `Seconds` parameter:

```
const job = new CronJob('0 13 12 * * *', function() {
  // rest of the codes ...
}
```